# If there's only one limit point, what's $\limsup_{n\to \infty} a_n$ and what's $\liminf_{n\to \infty} a_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

$a_n:=(-1)^n\cdot 1/n-2n^2(1+(-1)^n)+n/(n+1)$ with $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

I came to the conclusion that there's just a single limit point. If $H$ is the set of Limit points, it's $H=\{1\}$. How do I determine lim inf and lim sup if there's just a single element in the set?

Comment: If you want to talk about lim sup and lim inf using limit points, you have to include the ones at $\pm \infty$.

Comment: I posted a question kinda similar to this. The answers were great and could benefit you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3238500/let-x-n-be-a-bounded-sequence-and-u-limsup-x-n-let-e-be-set-of-limits-of

Comment: Proving $\liminf a_n$ wouldn't be too difficult. Show that $(a_n)$ is not bounded below, therefore $\liminf a_n = -\infty$. Also it is easy to prove $(a_n)$ is bounded above since it is the sum of sequences that are also bounded above. I don't know how to prove $\limsup a_n = 1$ however.

Comment: The subsequence $(a_{2k-1})_k$ tends to $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lim \inf a_n$ is the smallest limit point of the sequence and $\lim \sup a_n$ is the largest limit point. (In fact some books use this as the definition of $\lim \inf$ and $\lim \sup$). Hence $\lim \sup a_n =\lim \inf a_n=1$ which implies that $a_n \to 1$.

Comment: So both are $=1$, thanks for your help! :-) Can you give any source? Kind regards.

Comment: You can use Proposition 3.4.4 of https://mathcs.org/analysis/reals/numseq/limsup.html

Comment: In my text book, it is defined like this: Let $H$ be the set of all limit points of $(a_n)_n$. Then $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n:=\begin{cases}\sup H, \text{ if } (a_n)_n \text{is bounded above} \\ \infty, \text{ else}\end{cases}$ and $\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n:=\begin{cases}\inf H, \text{ if } (a_n)_n \text{is bounded below} \\ -\infty, \text{ else}\end{cases}$.     So what you propose is that $\sup H=1$ and $\inf H=1$, right?

Answer (score 0):

Since $(-1)^n \frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 0$ and $\frac{n}{n+1} \rightarrow 1$, you can focus on the sequence $b_n = -2n^2(1 + (-1)^n)$. Its only subsequential limits are $\lim b_{2n + 1}=0$ and $\lim b_{2n}=-\infty$. In fact, if $b_{n_k}$ converges, it must have only odd(or even) indexes $n_k$ for large $k$, and so it converges to $0$ or $-\infty$. So $1$ and $-\infty$ are the only subsequential limits of $a_n$.